# Xamarin - A remote error occurred in the connected mac. ... Connection is finished

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

The connection had been working for a while and then suddenly I started getting a flurry of error messages that resulted with a final "... connection is finished" error.

After a few attempts, I was able to screen capture one of the preceding messages and came up with this:

A Remote error occurred in the connected Mac
XCode couldn't be found at /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools.  Please specify the right location in Visual Studio under 'Tools > Options > Xamarin > iOS Settings' or ensure that uit is installed properly at the default location ('/Applications/Xcode.app')

[image: A remote error has occurred screen shot.]

I tried restarting visual studio on the PC, and Visual Studio and XCode on the mac, but no dice.

Answer (score 11):

I solved this problem by going back and checking that XCode command line tools was setup properly.  After a recent ios update,  the Xcode command line tools had been "deconfigured".  The fix was pretty simple.  I just had to go back into Xcode > Preferences > Locations and reselect the command line tools from the dropdown.  It wasn't an obvious or easy find, but it was a simple fix once you knew what to look for.

[image: Xcode Command Line fix]

Comment: You are a life saver!! Why does this kind of thing happen every time I update either VS or XCode?!

Comment: for me, it was the installation of homebrew that triggered a reinstallation of xcode command line tools with the above effect. kudos!